# IE absolute positioned <div> inside <td> relative to <tr> with position: relative

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have an issue, described in title. I have a table, div inside td of this table.
I want to position this div relative to table row, so I set tr position to relative and div position to absolute. It works fine in Firefox, but in IE it works unexpectedly for me. 
There is a code:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="panel"></div>
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>a</td>
            <td>s</td>
            <td><div class="problem-div">i'm here</div></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
table {
    border: 1px solid;
    table-layout: fixed;
    width: 100%
}

tr {
    position: relative
}

.panel {
    height: 50px;
    background-color: red
}
.problem-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

There is fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/L7nczrsp/5/
Help me to understand what I'm doing wrong, please.

**UPDATE1**
Thanks to @James we now know that position for table elements is undefined http://w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

**But**, we can set td position to relative instead of setting this styles to tr. It works fine. **But** it still conflicts with w3.

**But** Thanks to @ShabanKhan for idea, we can put relative positioned div into td and put our problem-div into this div. Seems to work. There is updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/meatwas/akkLxjpp/1/

Comment: IE11 looks fine, I would not expect this to work in olders versions of IE

Comment: Wouldn't this work if you add `position:relative` to `td`?

Comment: @James yes! I forgot to tell about it. It works good both in IE and FF, but what's wrong with tr?

Comment: @Luizgrs I'm using IE11 too. It's not in compatibility mode as I know. Can you make a screenshot please?

Comment: @МихаилКачалов it looks like relative positioning is undefined with table elements http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

Comment: @James, oh, I see. According to this, even positioning relative to <td> is a bad idea even if it's working? Thank You

Comment: @МихаилКачалов If something is "officially" problematic, then it would be best not to use it, even if it seems to work fine in all the browsers you've tested. There are other browsers out there that you haven't tested!

Comment: In Chrome on Mac looks same bad

Answer (score 0):

Positioning do not work on table properties try to add a div to make it position relative.

Comment: It does work with td somehow. If I understand you correctly, you suggest to place additional <div> container into <td>? I tried and it seems to work despite some position issues. Thank you @ShabanKhan

Answer (score 0):

If you add `position: relative` to the `table`, so it works well in Chrome, FF and Safari

There is your on [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/L7nczrsp/7/) with this idea.

Comment: yes, but positioning is relative to table not relative to row.

Comment: I have no idea what is your goal, it should be the result. If you add the real use of it would have been much better. I think you use solutions that would normally never used it.